# Myeclipse - mysql driver problem

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, maven, myeclipse

I have generated a CRUD application (in the trail version).
When I run it (in myeclipse tomcat) i get JDBC Exception:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

I have the dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

I also see the jar in myeclipse tomcat:
`/home/username/Workspaces/MyEclipse for Spring 9/.metadata/.me_tcat/webapps/Test1/WEB-INF/lib`

**This is my tomcat TREE**
http://pastie.org/2464591

Answer (score 0):

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException

You're apparently using Tomcat's builtin DBCP connection pooled datasource by a `<Resource>` configuration in `context.xml`. That's perfectly fine. But since it's Tomcat who is managing the datasource (and thus not your webapp!), the JDBC driver JAR file needs to be supplied to Tomcat (and thus not to your webapp!).

Drop the JAR file in Tomcat's `/lib` folder and this exception should disappear. If you can't afford moving the JAR due to some (silly) business restrictions or something, then you should create the datasource yourself in the webapp. A `ServletContextListener` is a good place.

Comment: I have placed it in /home/username/Workspaces/MyEclipse for Spring 9/.metadata/.me_tcat/webapps/Test1/WEB-INF/lib isn't that enough? thanks , I also added a link to the tomcat tree. thanks